# How do I filter a dataset to matching information in Excel?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a rather large dataset, and I was curious what the best method for filtering the dataset would be. I've been asked to find out how many orders we have in the system *do not* have an installation on them. The dataset is structured like below:

[image: Table Image]

So, I can't just put a filter on Material, and exclude Install, because order 123 did have one. Rather, I would want to filter to order 456 because there is no install on it.

I have tried =COUNTIF(B:B,"<>Install"), but it only counts the number of lines that do not have an install.

Surely, there's some kind of formula that can either be applied down the dataset, or an arrayformula() in Google Sheets, to help with this type of dataset filtering.

Update: Scott Craner's answer worked perfectly!

Any help/advice you all could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `=COUNTIF(B:B,"<>Install")` with maybe a -x where x is the number of header rows with text/numbers?  I am really confused by _"filter to..."_  and also by _"So, I can't just put a filter on Material, and exclude Install, because order 123 did have one."_

Comment: is the answer for your sample data 4?

Comment: Hmm, so I need to count the number of orders that don't have an Install code on them. Wouldn't that formula count the total number of lines that don't have Install? Since the dataset is at the line item of the order number, the order number is replicated multiple times.

Comment: Ideally, I would be able to filter the dataset, and just show Order Number 456 (and any other order that doesn't have Installs)

Comment: Sorry I did not understand the question until I saw Scott's answer.  Apparently did not have enough sleep on the weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a column put:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"=Install")<>0
```

[image]

Then filter out the `TRUE`

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Scott! Worked perfectly!